# SwiftUI large font with minimum scale is not aligned in centre

Tags: text, fonts, scale, swiftui, preview

Goal is to show a text the largest possible on the screen in any orientation so the solution I had in mind was to make the font size considerably big but add a minimum scale factor modifier to it such as the following.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("U")
            .font(.system(size: 2000
                )) .multilineTextAlignment(.center).minimumScaleFactor(0.001).padding()   
    }
}
```

how ever what is shown on canvas is the picture below and is trimmed on the right side.

[image: The U is trimmer on the right side, why? and how to fix it?]

Answer (score 1):

This will achieve the look you are after:

```
    Text("U")
        .font(.system(size: 2000))
        .minimumScaleFactor(.leastNonzeroMagnitude)
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and still “U” is not centered on the screen.

Comment: All SwiftUI Views are entered within their parent by default. The problem you are facing is with San Fransisco and how letters of that font are placed within the space allocated for them. You need a monospaced font, try Menlo for example: `.font(.custom("Menlo", size: 2000))`

Comment: @LuLuGaGa thank you - this is working well in my testing. Is there some reasoning or documentation behind `.minimumScaleFactor(.leastNonzeroMagnitude)` working better than `.minimumScaleFactor(0.5)` or any other set value as the minimum?